# How can I download a gene sequence from GenBank (NCBI)?

Tags: bioinformatics, molecular-genetics, genomics

Could you tell me the steps to find and download a gene sequence from GeneBank?

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: I think you can very easily find the steps for this with a little research.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to the [NCBI website](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/), fill the search field with relevant information in the upper part of page, select "nucleotide" from the drop-down menu just to the left of the search field and click search. You will get a list of items, by clicking "FASTA" link below any of them will bring you the corresponding sequence. 
Depending on your interest, you can choose other databases from that menu, and some of them are interlinked. For example you can do the search by selecting "gene" instead of "nucleotide" and when displaying a selected gene info, you can see the links that lead to nucleotide database for getting the sequence.